# App Engine : sub folder in templates

Tags: python, google-app-engine, templates

I'm using `template` to separate HTML and Python Code. I create templates folder. in this folder, I create index.html. Here is my code :

```
template_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'templates')
jinja_environment = jinja2.Environment(autoescape=True, loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(template_dir))

def render(self, template, **params):
        t = jinja_environment.get_template(template)
        return t.render(params)
```

And using render('index.html') : successful, no problem.

But when I create sub folder : templates/blog and in this folder, I create blog.html. I change the template above from `templates` to `templates/blog`. Here is my code :

```
template_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'templates/blog')
jinja_environment = jinja2.Environment(autoescape=True, loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(template_dir))
```

but, when I use render('blog.html') I have received error : `TemplateNotFound: blog.html`.

Please help me.

Thanks :)

Comment: Could you show your directory tree? And try moving `blog.html` to the `templates` folder to see if it works. Maybe the jinja loader isn't getting the directory argument you are passing it. And as it defaults to `templates`, most of the stuff from your first example is unneeded.

Comment: @mjibson when I move blog from templates\blog to template, it works. Maybe, jinja doesn't goto sub-folder. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: Did you tried os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'templates', 'blog')  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add more folders in jinja2 enviroment:

```
jinja_environment = jinja2.Environment(
  loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(['templates', 'templates\blog'])
)
```

Comment: syntax is incorrect, add a close bracket ) at the end.